# There is no /etc/gdm directory?

Tags: gdm

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 and trying to add some startup scripts to gdm login screen.
I found 4 places in documentation of gdm to do so:

1. /etc/gdm/Init
2. /etc/gdm/PostLogin
3. /etc/gdm/PreSession
4. /etc/gdm/PostSession

but as the matter of fact, there is no /etc/gdm directory in my linux machine.
Can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: As neon_overload says, lightdm is replaced by gdm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses lightdm instead of gdm by default, unless you have installed Ubuntu Gnome.

You should probably look into how you can achieve the same things in lightdm.

Or you can install GDM if you want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/gdm/filelist), the gdm package should contain all `/etc/gdm/*/Default` scripts.
If gdm is completely installed the packages should be there.

Please, **check if gdm is installed**:

```
dpkg --list | grep gdm
ii  gdm                                       3.0.4-0ubuntu15.3                       GNOME Display Manager
```

`ii` means it's installed completely. If the command gives no output, gdm is not installed.

**Installing gdm:**

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```